# How to estimate the size and the hashkeys value of cluster

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, cluster-computing, clustered-index

I would love to understand more how I should calculate or estimate the size and the haskeys value when creating a cluster ?

Should it be based on table size? Column size?

I'm aware is documented [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5001.htm) but I still don't understand it properly

Here is my cluster

```
CREATE  CLUSTER clust (srvr_id INTEGER ) 
    SIZE 1024 SINGLE TABLE HASHKEYS 11;
```

here is my table for the cluster

```
CREATE TABLE Table_clust
CLUSTER clust (value2)
AS SELECT * FROM Table  ;
```

Best regards,

Bass